# Hashmap internal flow while getting Value

Tags: java, string, dictionary

When I write

```
String str1 = new String("hello");
String str2 = new String("hello");
```

afaik, even though the String contents are same, `str1` and `str2` will point to separate memory location as it will refer in heap and not in pool.

In this case, when I execute the below program, why  is it giving me the value when the two instances (Key) of string are different? then why the same is not happening with user defined objects?

```
String str1 = new String("hello");
String str2 = new String("hello");
AB obj1 = new AB();
BC obj2 = new BC();

HashMap h = new HashMap();
h.put(str1, "data");
h.put(obj1, "data1");

System.out.println(h.get(str2));
System.out.println(h.get(obj2));

class AB {
  int code = 10;
}

class BC {
  int code = 10;
}
```

Output:

```
data
null
```

Comment: str1 and str2 are not the "same", they are equals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because HashMap will first find the correct bucket based on the hashcode of the string object.Once it finds the bucket, after that it will invoke the Equals method to compare the key.

Ps note that Equals comparions is overriden by String class hence it compares not just on the basis of reference but based on content.

Answer (score 1):

Because HashMap uses `equals` to compare keys. Although your 2 strings are different instances, they are [equal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Your custom objects can't be equal because they are not even of the same type. Even if they were of the same type, unless you override the [`equals` method inherited from `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), 2 different instances (created with `new`) won't be equal.

Note that if you override `equals`, you also need to override `hashCode` to avoid unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap.get() function call the Object.hashCode() method to create the key value.
But, String class override this method and it calculates from values.
If we override the hashCode function for these (AB and BC) classes, we will find same solution.

String hashCode():

```
public int hashCode() {
int h = hash;
    int len = count;
if (h == 0 && len > 0) {
    int off = offset;
    char val[] = value; // get value of string.

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

And this is HashMap.get() method

```
public V get(Object key) {
    if (key == null)
        return getForNullKey();
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());// it calculate at here.
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
         e != null;
         e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
            return e.value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an agreement while using some object as key in hashmap
you must override hashcode and equals methods
now since String class does it you are getting "data" from first sysout 
if you override hashcode and equals method of AB and BC in desired way you will get data1 from second sysout

and str1 and str2 will **not** point to separate memory location

Answer (score 0):

The `String`s are compared for their contents. not the actual object or reference.

Since `str1` and `str2` both have same contents, it's giving you the value from `HashMap`.

HashMap uses `equals` method to search for the exact key in it. Since `str1.equals(str2)` results in `true`, the key is found and so `get` method returns the value.

Try editing your classes as follows, and you'll be amazed:

```
class AB 
{   
    int code = 10; 
    public boolean equals(Object argument)
    {
        if(argument instanceof AB || argument instanceof BC)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}  

class BC 
{   
    int code = 10; 
    public boolean equals(Object argument)
    {
        if(argument instanceof AB || argument instanceof BC)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, your 2nd `System.out.println(h.get(obj2));` statement will also return it's mapped data.

Comment: @ramsinb: it can't have a real-time usage but may be helpful to OP to undestand the concept.

Comment: @Azodious, I have overridden equals and hashCode method and found that it doesn't only calls equals method for getting data. what I found is, while storing/putting data in a map it uses hashCode() method and while fetching/getting data back it uses hashCode() method to find out whether it is same or not, if it is not same then it will return null and if the hashCode found same then it call equals() method to find out the content is same or not.

Answer (score 0):

A map is implemented in such a way so as to utilise the hashCode and equals methods of a class.

Firstly when you add an instance of a class to a map the implementation of the map will place that instance in a bucket. This is why it is important to implement hashCode correctly in order to ensure buckets within the map are distributed effectively.

The use of the equals method is to determine which instance in the bucket is the instance you are after, thus it is important to implement the equals correctly.

In your case String implements hashCode and equals correctly whereas your user defined objects are not of the same type and therefore cannot be equal (you don't override equals or hashCode anyway).